# XOR = Best encryption?

Tags: keys, stream-cipher, one-time-pad, xor

If you have a TRULY random key (in binary) and you have a text (in binary) that you want to encrypt.

Can you simple XOR the key and the text?

Is that secure?

How secure?

Comment: Welcome to Crypto.SE. I recommend you checked out [one time pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad). Then, with a basic understanding on that, try searching this site for any questions that might pop up. I hope this helps.

Comment: I have already read that and did not quite find the answer. I don't need a super fancy answer just the questions I already have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XORing a key and message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) [is called a](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47/with-sufficient-randomness-is-xor-an-acceptable-mechanism-for-encrypting) [one time pad.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24332/key-length-requirement-in-a-simple-xor-implementation)  It is perfectly secure, providing confidentiality, when used correctly.  That last part is the hard part, along with finding a situation in which you only need confidentiality.

Comment: I think there are some conditionals that need to be added here. Not all keys will get the security you describe.

Comment: Absolutely. Clearly this is an incomplete answer to an insufficient question which we all hope will be followed by additional research.